# JavaScript Regular Expression to get words in quotes string

Tags: javascript, regex

Thanks for all, I met a problem in JavaScript, and the problem is:

I have a string: such as:

```
{"results":[{"id":"id1","text":"text1"},{"id":"id2","text":"text2"},{"id":"id3","text":"text3"}]}
```

Then, I want to get the string such as:

```
id1|text1|id2|text2|id3|text3
```

So how should I write the Regular Expression?

Thank you so much, and I am a new comer in StackOverFlow!

Comment: Why write a regex?  That's JSON!  Just parse it (with `JSON.parse()`), then build your string from the object (by looping over it).

Comment: You should not write a regular expression for JSON at all!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a string

That string is in [JSON format](http://json.org/), which works very well with JavaScript.

> So how should I write the Regular Expression?

You should not write a regular expression at all. If you did, you [only had two problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems):

> <s>`.replace(/(^.+?|"\},\{)?"id":"|","text":"|"}[^"]*$/g, "|").slice(1,-1)`</s>

Instead, [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the string into an object, and extract the id-text pairs from there:

```
var result = JSON.parse(string).results.map(function(el) {
    return el.id+"|"+el.text;
}).join("|");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tried your regular expression, and it works. But I don't make it work with the JSON, maybe I have something wrong with that, because I am not familiar with that. I used to alert(result) or alert(result.id) and neither of them show something.

Comment: You should be getting familiar with JSON easier than with that horrible regex. Do *not* use it only because it does work on that simple input.